Failed to pull image from Artifactory Jfrog as private repo for kubernetes
I'm trying to use Artifactory Jfrog as private repository for my Kubernetes cluster which uses containerd as deamon,
However, this repo works fine with docker when I set the same repository address that was working fine with docker in Kubernetes deployment I keep getting this error when describe pod events
failed to pull and unpack image"": failed to resolve reference"": failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: authorization server did not include a token in the response
